# GAE/webapp2: Serving Excel file created by script using xlwt

Tags: python, google-app-engine, webapp2, xlwt

I am trying to use google app engine, [`webapp2`](https://webapp-improved.appspot.com/index.html) and a script based on [`xlwt`](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/xlwt) that calls its `save` method to create a specific excel file *in situ* and let it be downloaded by the user.

Now I have tried several different approaches according to various websites, but none so far yielded any success. I will outline my tries and if any of you knows how to get it to work, I would be very grateful.

Thanks a lot in advance. If you need any more information, please let me know and I will update it the moment, I see it.

**NOTE**
`xls_create(arg, filename_or_stream)` is the function that calls xlwt.save() and creates the excel file to be downloaded.

---

**Try 1: "Using StreamIO"**
This was my best try so far. It gave me even an excel file, but for some reason it did not completely "finish the content". It looked like it only wrote about a quarter of what it should have written. On checking my script stand_alone it all worked fine, so I am 100% confident that it was not a problem with my script, but with the code below.

*Addendum*
It turns out that the main mistake here was that in the line `a_list = self.request.get('a_list')`, I did not put `allow_multiple=True`. Because of this only the first value of the list, I was passing over, was being used.

I recommend AlexMartelli's minimal example of how to use xlwt, webapp2 and GAE below to do something similar to me.

```
class XLSCreator(webapp2.RequestHandler):

    def post(self):
        self.response.headers['Content-Type'] = 'application/vnd.ms-excel'
        a_list = self.request.get('a_list')

        # create a stringIO object
        output = StringIO.StringIO()

        # Create file in memory
        xls_create(a_list, output)

        # Set back to start
        output.seek(0)
        self.response.out.write(output.getvalue())

        # When uncommented, process does not finish
        #output.close()
```

---

**Try 2:**
The next two are desperation tries ;) I picked up from code all over and just stuck it in and tried. Sadly, no luck.

class XLSCreator(webapp2.RequestHandler):

```
def post(self):

    fname = 'excelfile.xls'
    self.response.headers['Content-Type'] = 'application/vnd.ms-excel'
    self.response.headers['Content-Disposition'] = 'attachment; filename="%s"' % fname
    a_list = self.request.get('a_list')
    self.response.out.write(xls_create(a_list, fname))
```

---

**Try 3:**

class XLSCreator(webapp2.RequestHandler):

```
def post(self):

    fname = 'excelfile.xls'
    self.response.headers['Content-Type'] = 'application/vnd.ms-excel'
    self.response.headers['Content-Disposition'] = 'attachment; filename="%s"' % fname
    a_list = self.request.get('a_list')

    xls_create(a_list, self.response.out)
```

Comment: Why the `seek(0)`?  `getvalue` 'the entire contents of the “file”'.  Also, where's the code for `xls_save`?  Your bug might be hiding there.

Comment: @AlexMartelli: I tested xls_create ad absurdum and it works just fine when I use it on its own, so I can confidently say that it is not a factor. For easiness sake, I wanted to leave it out.
`seek(0)` I found I needed to use streams (see an example for StreamIO)

Comment: "sigh", it turned out there was a lot more wrong with my code than I thought. The xls_create was the one thing that "did" work.

I will annotate my answer at the Try 1: StreamIO example, because the problem was mis-identified on my part

Comment: @AlexMartelli: I finally found the example where I got the `seek(0)` part from. http://flask.pocoo.org/snippets/32/   I was working with flask before and I saw it there... If it is unnecessary, I wonder why it is in there...

Comment: Good question -- maybe the author of that snippet was experimenting with various approaches and when the current one worked didn't notice that it actually included useless extras.  In the past I've reviewed working code which just happened to have e.g an `a=b+c` line twice (second one clearly useless but innocuous) -- that one no doubt was just a miniscule editor accident, but in a sense there's some similarity here:-).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's a "hello world" (!) GAE handler trying to do the kind of thing you're talking about: this is `main.py`, to which `app.yaml` routes all URLs; I've copied `xlwt/*.py` into the subdirectory `xlwt` of the directory in which `main.py` and `app.yaml` live.

```
import webapp2
import StringIO
import xlwt

def makeit():
    workbook = xlwt.Workbook() 
    sheet = workbook.add_sheet("Hello World") 
    sheet.write(0, 0, 'Hello world!')
    out = StringIO.StringIO()
    workbook.save(out)
    return out

class MainHandler(webapp2.RequestHandler):
    def get(self):
        self.response.headers['Content-Type'] = 'application/vnd.ms-excel'
        out = makeit()
        self.response.write(out.getvalue())

app = webapp2.WSGIApplication([
    ('/', MainHandler)
], debug=True)
```

Visiting the `/` on this GAE app with my Chrome browser downloads a `download.xls` file (5632 bytes) which the Mac's `Preview` app is happy to visualize as the one-cell spreadsheet it is.

Now, please try to modify this minimally until it reproduces the bug you observe (maybe the resulting `xls` would serialize to more than 32MB, which is documented as the maximum size of an App Engine response?) -- that should help diagnose the root cause of your problem, which, now we know, is not the simple issue of using `xlwt.save` with a `StringIO` argument (I also tried the unneeded `out.seek(0)` and while unneeded it still produces the right result:-).

Comment: As annotated inline above. The main mistake was due to the lacking function variable `allow_multiple=True` in `self.request.get('a_list')`.  

While your answer did not solve the issue, it helped me to further minimise the code and isolate the potential sources of error. In addition, it gives a good minimal example of GAE, webapp2 and xlwt ;)